# non-archimedean geometry

Tags: geometry

> **Statement of the archimedean axiom**: If AB and CD are any segments then
> there exists a number $n$ such that $n$ segments CD constructed
> contiguously from A, along the ray from A through B, will pass beyond
> the point B.

We're looking for a model that satisfies incidence, order and congruence sets of axioms but not the Archimedean axiom.

One such model is Veronese model, which defines ordering as follows:

$$ (x_1 , y_1 ) > (x_2 , y_2 ) \Longleftrightarrow y_1 > y_2 ∨ ((y_1 = y_2 ) ∧ x_1 > x_2 ) $$

and the point $(x,y)$ lies between $(x_1 , y_1 )$ and $(x_2 , y_2 )$ if and only if either $ (x_1 , y_1 ) < (x , y ) < (x_2 , y_2 )$ or $(x_1 , y_1 ) > (x_0 , y_0 ) > (x_2 , y_2 ). $

so my question is, how does this "break" Archimedean axiom? we can simply lay off any segment upon a point along the ray containing the segment in a given direction and "exceed" the segment.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to this question, a straightforward example is the line segment AB where A(0,k) and B(1,k) in addition to the segment CD where C(0,k) and D(0,c). no matter how many times you "append" CD along the ray containing AB, you'll never go beyond D.